# how to change the view

Tags: python, python-2.7, abaqus

```
odbname = data.jobname + '.odb'
        mySession  = session.openOdb(name = odbname)
        myViewport = session.viewports["Viewport: 1"]
        #plot stress
        myViewport.setValues(displayedObject=mySession)
        myViewport.odbDisplay.display.setValues(plotState=(CONTOURS_ON_DEF,))
        myViewport.view.fitView()
        session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].viewportAnnotationOptions.setValues(
        legendFont='-*-verdana-medium-r-normal-*-*-120-*-*-p-*-*-*')
```

when i run this program am able to see the view iso i need to get the view in front view direction so can anyone tell me how to change to view using python coding

this are my import module

```
from abaqus import *                # from the main library
from caeModules import *            # import the modules
from abaqusConstants import *       # constants we need
from math import fabs
from abaqus import backwardCompatibility
backwardCompatibility.setValues(reportDeprecated=False)
import section
import regionToolset
import displayGroupMdbToolset as dgm
import part
import material
import assembly
import step
import interaction
import load
import mesh
import optimization
import job
import sketch
import visualization
import xyPlot
import displayGroupOdbToolset as dgo
import connectorBehavior
```

Comment: It would be a Good Idea to tell people what modules you are using.

Comment: i am new to programing so i have no idea abt modules ?

Comment: What are the `import` statements in your program?

Answer (score 1):

For abaqus the easiest thing to do watch the replay output generated by abaqus cae. Open the model manually in CAE and change the view to what you would like to see. Abaqus writes a python replay file of all the actions the user takes in the CAE window. Navigate to your working folder and find the file named abaqus.rpy. The last lines in that will be the python commands to replicate your actions in CAE.